# multiple batch queries within transaction template

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions, transactionmanager

I am trying to delete every 100 records read from a file in 3 tables,using spring jdbc batch delete  .If i wrap the logic inside a transactionTemplate, is it going to work as expected, e.g lets say i am creating 3 batch out of 300 records and wrapping the logic inside a transaction ,then is the transaction going to roll back 1st and 2nd batch, if 3rd batch got a problem.My code is included in the question for reference. I am writing the below code to achieve what i have explained above, is my code correct?

```
TransactionTemplate txnTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(txnManager);
txnTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
    @Override
    public void doInTransactionWithoutResult(final TransactionStatus status) { 
        try {
            deleteFromABCTable(jdbcTemplate, successList);
            deleteFromDEFTable(jdbcTemplate, successList);
            deleteFromXYZTable(jdbcTemplate, successList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
             status.setRollbackOnly();
             throw e;
        }
    }
});
```

My delete methods :-

```
   private void deleteFromABCTable(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, List 
    successList) {
    try {
        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
                "delete from ABC where document_id in (select document_id 
    from ABC where item in(?)))",
                new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                    @Override
                    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) 
    throws SQLException {
                        ps.setString(0, successList.get(i));
                    } });
    } catch (Exception e) { }
```

Comment: My delete methods :-
`code` private void deleteFromABCTable(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, List successList) {
        try {
            jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
                    "delete from ABC where document_id in (select document_id from ABC where item in(?)))",
                    new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                        @Override
                        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                            ps.setString(0, successList.get(i));
                        } });
        } catch (Exception e) { } `code`

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55655448/edit) your question and add this information on it. It is hard to read code in comments

Comment: @JorgeCampos edited as per your advice